# Easy ODE Separable Equation but can't see the seperation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble seeing this equation as separable. What am I missing? I can't seem to get it in the correct form.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x+xy}{y^2+1}$$

The closest I can get it is as follows and I can't integrate it.

$$dy \frac{y^2+1}{2+y}={xdx}$$

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Use long division or synthetic division to divide $y+2$ into $y^2+1$.

Comment: anyway, to do this without long division?

Comment: You might do it my substituting $u=y+2$.

Comment: Equivalently put $z=y+2; y=z-2$ which does the same job as division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the numerator as:
$$f(y)=y^2+1=y^2+2y-2y+1$$
$$f(y)=y(y+2)-2y-4+4+1$$
$$f(y)=y(y+2)-2(y+2)+5$$
$$\dfrac  {f(y)}{y+2}=y-2+\dfrac 5 {y+2}$$
Then integrate:
$$\int \dfrac  {y^2+1}{y+2}=\int ydy-2\int dy+5 \int \dfrac {dy} {y+2}$$

Comment: How do I know to do that?

Comment: yes, but i mean what gave you the idea to do that?

Comment: I can't follow with the -4 + 4 + 1

Comment: I'm sorry no not really.

Comment: @Ziggy: You don't need to get an **idea** to do that, since there is a well-known **algorithm** that you can follow for integrating rational functions: (1) If needed (namely if the degree of the numerator is not already less than the degree of the denominator), do polynomial division. (2) If needed (namely if you can't already integrate what you have), do partial fractions decomposition. (3) Integrate the partial fractions (using known methods).

Comment: And what's done in this answer is nothing but step (1) of this algorithm: divide $y^2+1$ by $y+2$.